# Running Graphical applications in linux instance on google compute engine

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to setup OpenFOAM on google compute engine for running simulations which are currently very heavy for my quad core system that I'm using.

Till now I've managed to install OpenFOAM,ParaView and vncserver.
Through the vnc server I'm able to view the explorer and navigate through the folders and do basic editing stuff.

But when I'm trying to run paraFoam(for post processing) I get an error saying 
"*cannot open display*"
same with xclock and xterm

I have checked my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on VM to check X11Forwarding, which is enabled.

Checking the same on my local machine at /etc/ssh/ssh_config has the following

ForwardAgent no
ForwardX11 no
ForwardX11Trusted yes

VM is running on 16.04Ubuntu LTS and so is the local machine.

Any help on how to get the graphical applications running on the VM instance on google compute engine would be very helpful.

Comment: I thought *"google compute engine"* was a typo or something, turns out [it's really a thing - Google VM or some sort](https://cloud.google.com/compute/)

Comment: Paraview makes use of OpenGL for data visualisation, do you  know if 3D can be forwarded by X11?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but do correct me if so.After going through X11 on wikipedia, I think X11 can forward both 2dD and 3D .

Answer (score 2):

Well, running an X server on a headless machine is kind of tricky, because, basically, the Virtual Machine may NOT have any graphical cards for that. You may want to try run an X server, which stores the bitmap into the memory, instead of actually outputting it into a graphical card - called Xvfb. Don't expect any hardware acceleration for graphics though, but that may be a good start.

Install and run Xvfb: `Xvfb :0 -screen 0 640x480x24` (change the resolution as needed).
Then, run your application: `DISPLAY=:0 yourbinary`
If the app starts, it's half of the job done. Then, you may want to know what actually happens inside. Install x11vnc and run it similarily to the app: `DISPLAY=:0 x11vnc`. You may need to configure it to make it secure enough for your needs. Then just connect via VNC to see what's going on inside.

Comment: This answer really helped me understand the challenges, particularly the part about a "`headless machine`".  In retrospect, it's obvious that if the instance isn't connected to a monitor, why would there be graphics cards?  I'm very glad I stumbled on this today; been confused about why X11 forwarding isn't working for at least 4 days now!

Comment: How do I "connect via VNC" ?  I tried both VNC Viewer and Remmina GUIs and fed in my instance's IP address, and neither connected

Comment: If I remember right, I used TightVNC Viewer to connect. And don't forget to specify the port.